# Keras model creates linear classification for make_moons data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to reproduce the model in this [WildML - Implementing a Neural Network From Scratch](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/) tutorial but using Keras instead. I've tried to use all of the same configurations as the tutorial, but I keep getting a linear classification even after tweaking the number of epochs, batch sizes, activation functions, and number of units in the hidden layer:

[image: classification graph]

Here's my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

import  numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import  sklearn
from    sklearn import datasets, linear_model

# Build model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=2, output_dim=3, activation="tanh", init="normal"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=2, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train
np.random.seed(0)
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(200, noise=0.20)
y_binary = to_categorical(y)
model.fit(X, y_binary, nb_epoch=100)

# Helper function to plot a decision boundary.
# If you don't fully understand this function don't worry, it just generates the contour plot below.
def plot_decision_boundary(pred_func):
    # Set min and max values and give it some padding
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
    h = 0.01
    # Generate a grid of points with distance h between them
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    # Predict the function value for the whole gid
    Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    # Plot the contour and training examples
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

# Predict and plot
plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: model.predict_classes(x, batch_size=200))
plt.title("Decision Boundary for hidden layer size 3")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I figured out the problem. If I remove the `np.random.seed(0)` and train for 2000 epochs, the output isn't always linear and occasionally gets to higher 90%+ accuracy:

[image]

It must have been that `np.random.seed(0)` led to the parameters being seeded poorly, and since I was fixing the random seeding I would see the same graph every time.

Comment: 2000 epochs?? why so much? Is there a threshold, beyond which the model starts to exhibit non-linear behavior?

Comment: This is not a satisfying analysis. You never tuned the learning-rate and batch-size. I'm pretty sure that a good learning-rate / Adam-learning will work much more robust. You also did skip a data-normalization-step, which is very important.

Comment: optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1) or optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1) and kernel_initializer="glorot_normal" seems to work well. Why SGD has problems with np.random.seed(0) is still an open question for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this problem, but I do not know why it should be solved. If you change the output layer's activation function to *'sigmoid'* instead of *'softmax'*, the system will work.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= . ['accuracy'])
```

From this, I can achieve an accuracy of 95% or greater. If I leave the above code in *softmax*, the linear classifier remains.

---

.